# Calculate elapsed time in php from time() function

Tags: php

If a user make error in the logging, and he changed his password in the last months, I want that it will notify him about it, like in Google. When the user changes his password, his old password enters the database in case he forgot his password (it asks him when was the last time he entered my website without a problem, the last password he remembers and more...). It also saves the time of the change in time() format. My question is how to calculate elapsed time from the change to now and write the time. if it changes this week I want it to write how many days passed and if doesn't changed it in this week it will write him how many weeks passed.
How to calculate it and "echo" the result in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `$timeOfChange` be the value of `time()` from the database, when the user last changed his or her password. Then you can use the following code snippet:

```
$diff = time() - $timeOfChange;
if ($diff <= 604800) { // 604800 seconds == 1 week
    echo floor($diff / 86400) . ' days'; // 86400 seconds == 1 day
} else {
    echo floor($diff / 604800) . ' weeks';
}
```

I wanted to keep the code simple, so I do not pay attention to special cases like '1 week' and '1 day', where the final 's' is not needed. So you may want to extend the code for such cases.